# How to effectively prevent fieldNameConflicts client-side when converting firestore docs using Codable?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

On my iOS Swift client I convert firestore docs to local instances using the Codable protocol.

```
class Event: Codable {
  @DocumentID var id: String!
}

guard let event = try! diff.document.data(as: Event.self)
```

However, some documents in the collection already have an `id` field. If they do, then Swift throws:

> Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: FirebaseFirestoreSwift.FirestoreDecodingError.fieldNameConflict("Field name ["id"] was found from document "events/6VQuDvdLBIKn06WCJeA0", cannot assign the document reference to this field.")

What would be the most effective way to prevent this `fieldNameConflict` on the Swift client if I can not be sure if the firestore doc will come with an `id` field or not? In case the firestore doc does come with an `id` field I would like it to be overwritten by the "inherent" firestore document id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a custom decoder. Here is a snippet to get you started:

```swift
extension Event: Codable {
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    if let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) {
      // any other attributes you might have:
      someAttribute = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .someAttribute) ?? ""

      // (1)
      if let docRef = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id) {
        id = docRef
      }
      else {
        // see https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7242
        id = try container.decode(DocumentID<String>.self, forKey: .id).wrappedValue
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code at (1) will first check if there is an `id` attribute on your document. Only if that's not the case, will it decode the document ID using the `@DocumentID` property wrapper.

As a side note, I'd also recommend using structs for your models. This will probably also help you avoid using the `!` operator.

Comment: I face several problems when implementing it. First, xCode tells me that this has to be a required initialiser, which therefore can't be in an extension. Once I moved it into the main class definition, xCode complains that I return from the initialiser without initialising all stored properties. Even though I have implemented an initialisation for all properties where you left the comment "any other attributes you might have". Do you know of a working example of this that you could link me to?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work :) Since you check for container by using if let, how do you handle the situation, if the container is not present? Because I had to remove that check to ensure xCode that all properties will be initialised.